# Mapbox dynamic markers in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, mapbox

Able to successfully set the mapbox viewpoint dynamically by passing the geocoder a street address stored in my database.

But rather than just setting the map view to the address, I want to draw a marker at the address' location.

```
Template.vendorPage.rendered = function(){


//get address from database by ID
address = function(){
    pathname =location.pathname.split("/"); 
    thisId = pathname[2]; 
    return Vendors.findOne({_id: thisId}).address
}
//set variable to the address function
thisAddress = address(); 

//draw the mapbox
L.mapbox.accessToken = '<My Token Here>';
var geocoder = L.mapbox.geocoder('mapbox.places-v1'),
    map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'alexnetsch.j786e624');

geocoder.query(thisAddress, showMap);

function showMap(err, data) {
    // The geocoder can return an area, like a city, or a
    // point, like an address. Here we handle both cases,
    // by fitting the map bounds to an area or zooming to a point.
    if (data.lbounds) {
        map.fitBounds(data.lbounds);
    } else if (data.latlng) {
        map.setView([data.latlng[0], data.latlng[1]], 16);
    }
}


}
```

Played around with the documentation for hours and can't figure it out. I'd like to simply pass the marker function 'thisAddress'

Seems like rather than setting the viewport, I could set the map to be zoomedin and centered around my marker.

Here is the example from the documentation but without Geocoding the location.

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYWxleG5ldHNjaCIsImEiOiJsX0V6Wl9NIn0.i14NX5hv3bkVIi075nOM2g';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-20v6611k')
    .setView([38.91338, -77.03236], 16);

L.mapbox.featureLayer({
    // this feature is in the GeoJSON format: see geojson.org
    // for the full specification
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        // coordinates here are in longitude, latitude order because
        // x, y is the standard for GeoJSON and many formats
        coordinates: [
          -77.03221142292,
          38.913371603574 
        ]
    },
    properties: {
        title: 'Peregrine Espresso',
        description: '1718 14th St NW, Washington, DC',
        // one can customize markers by adding simplestyle properties
        // https://www.mapbox.com/foundations/an-open-platform/#simplestyle
        'marker-size': 'large',
        'marker-color': '#BE9A6B',
        'marker-symbol': 'cafe'
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out finally.

```
Template.vendorPage.rendered = function(){
    address = function(){
        pathname =location.pathname.split("/"); 
        thisId = pathname[2]; 
        return Vendors.findOne({_id: thisId}).address
    }

    thisAddress = address(); 

    //draw the mapbox
    L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYWxleG5ldHNjaCIsImEiOiJsX0V6Wl9NIn0.i14NX5hv3bkVIi075nOM2g';
    var geocoder = L.mapbox.geocoder('mapbox.places-v1'),
        map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'alexnetsch.j786e624');

    geocoder.query(thisAddress, showMap);

    function showMap(err, data) {
        // The geocoder can return an area, like a city, or a
        // point, like an address. Here we handle both cases,
        // by fitting the map bounds to an area or zooming to a point.
        if (data.lbounds) {
            map.fitBounds(data.lbounds);
        } else if (data.latlng) {
            map.setView([data.latlng[0], data.latlng[1]], 16);
        }
    }

    var addMarker;
    addMarker = function(geocoder, map, placeName) {
      return geocoder.query(placeName, function(error, result) {
        var marker;
        marker = L.marker(result.latlng);
        return marker.addTo(map);
      });
    };

    addMarker(geocoder, map, thisAddress);
```